# R: Compilation failed for package dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to install dplyr on R version 3.1.1 for RHEL:

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
    Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

    locale:
     [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
     [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
     [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
     [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
     [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
    [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

I downloaded an archived version of dplyr here which should be compatible: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr

```
    xxxxx-2.desktop% wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.2.tar.gz
```

However, when I try to install the package it gives this compilation error:

```
    xxxxx-2.desktop% R CMD INSTALL dplyr_0.3.tar.gz
    * installing to library â/home/xxxxx/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1â
    * installing *source* package âdplyrâ ...
    ** package âdplyrâ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs
    g++ -I/usr/share/R-3.1.1/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/xxxxx/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/xxxxx/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BH/include"   -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.       cpp -o RcppExports.o
    /home/xxxxx/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In member function âvoid Rcpp::Date::update_tm()â:
    /home/xxxxx/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h:108: warning: converting to âtime_tâ from âdoubleâ
    /home/xxxxx/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In function âRcpp::Date Rcpp::operator+(const Rcpp::Date&, int)â:
    /home/xxxxx/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h:139: warning: converting to âtime_tâ from âdoubleâ
    ../inst/include/dplyr/JoinVisitorImpl.h: In constructor âdplyr::JoinFactorStringVisitor::JoinFactorStringVisitor(const Rcpp::IntegerVector&, const Rcpp::CharacterVector&)â:
    ../inst/include/dplyr/JoinVisitorImpl.h:177: error: invalid conversion from âconst int*â to âint*â
    ../inst/include/dplyr/JoinVisitorImpl.h: In constructor âdplyr::JoinStringFactorVisitor::JoinStringFactorVisitor(const Rcpp::CharacterVector&, const Rcpp::IntegerVector&)â:
    ../inst/include/dplyr/JoinVisitorImpl.h:238: error: invalid conversion from âconst int*â to âint*â
    make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package âdplyrâ
```

edit: other posts suggest this may be a compiler issue (https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1317), is there any way for me to update my compiler?

Comment: I suppose you have tried other versions as well, right?

Comment: Yes - I've tried dplyr versions 0.1, 0.1.3, 0.2, and 0.3, all with the same issue.

Comment: Your RHEL version and compiler may be too old. What does `g++ --version` say?

Comment: `xxxxx-2.desktop% g++ --version`

`g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)`

`Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`